# userspace taking too long at boot so how can i boot fast..?

Tags: linux, boot

Startup finished in 3.148s (firmware) + 3.502s (loader) + 3.048s (kernel) + 1min 10.343s (userspace) = 1min 20.042s  graphical.target reached after 1min 10.188s in userspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the obvious suggestion would be to upgrade the disk to a fast SSD drive.

Otherwise the startup times you show are quite normal, and representative for my Ubuntu and Kali machines to start up.

In my overall experience, drive speed is the biggest determinant of starting speed (independent of operating system).  5400-rpm drives really drag down startup.

Comment: ThankYou .. But i have 6 gb ram and i want to delay some processes at boot so.. how can i..?

Comment: As long as there is sufficient memory to start, that will not affect the start up speed much.  You would have to analyze the processes you do not want to run. Your overall start up speed is pretty normal.

Comment: Ohkay.. Thank you so much dude..